# I am running a Perl script in Windows 7 and have issues about finding PID of the currently running batch file

Tags: perl, windows-7

I am starting the new independent Perl script[using system(Start command)] from the the parent perl script. I am writing the PID of the child script into one file and I read it in the parent script so that whenever I want to end the child process I can simply kill using its PID.

But I am calling another batch file using the child process ex system("somebatchfile) from the child script. Here My PID will change and I am unable to close it until batch file finishes it's work. I am unable to get the PID of the batch file. I tried using the fork function but anyway calling a batch file will create other PID of its own.

My code is as follows.

Parent script: start a new script and read PID and kill the started script if needed.

Child script:

```
open(PID,">PID_Value.txt");
print PID "\$Process_id=$$"; # write the PID of child script
close(PID);
system("somebatch file name"); # I am using Windows 7
```

Answer (score 2):

How about appending the pid to the file instead?

```
open(PID, ">>PID_Value.txt");
print PID "$$\n";
close(PID);
```

Then you won't be overwriting the other pids.

Alternatively you can use `fork()` and `exec()` to spawn the child process, and then the parent would get the child's pid directly:

```
my $pid = fork();
die "fork failed: $!" unless defined($pid);
if ($pid) {
  push(@child_pids, $pid); # parent executes this
} else {
  # child executes here
  exec("somebatch file name")
    or die "failed to exec somebatch file name: $!";
}
```

This would be the Unix-way to do it. But if you are using Cygwin perl under Windows 7, I would also suggest using `Win32::Process::Create(...)` since that creates a real Windows process.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a child process which in turn creates another process to do the batch processing, and assuming you cannot alter the batch code, I suspect the only way to selectively kill the batch process will be to iterate over all running process names (using Win32::Process::Info) to identify the PID of the batch and then kill it.